# Comparación entre dos string como vectores

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con hacer lo siguiente: Comparar una secuencia de string con otras secuencias.
Por ejemplo, ver si la cadena1 coincide en algún momento con la cadenaprincipal.
He intentado esto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string cadena1= "ABC";
    string cadena2 = "CAA";
    string cadenaprincipal="BBACCAABCAA";
    int k = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < cadenaprincipal.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cadena1.length(); j++){
            if(cadenaprincipal.at(i) ==  cadena1.at(j)){
                k++;
                if(k == cadena1.length()){
                    n++;
                }
                
            }else{
                cout << "Nel" << endl;
                k = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Total de coincidencias: " << n  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Te falla la lógica? ¿Tienes problemas de compilación? ¿Obtienes datos inesperados?

Answer (score 1):

Tu único problema es que estás comparando sólo una letra de la cadena principal con toda la cadena de la otra.
Haces esto:

```
cadena1= "ABC";
cadenaprincipal = "BBACCAABCAA";
```

Para **`i = 0`**:(Primer `for`)

```
cadenaprincipal.at(0) = B
```

Entramos al siguiente `for` y comparamos:

```
if("B" ==  cadena1.at(j))
```

Aquí, "B" no variará porque tomará ese valor hasta haber terminado el for anidado. Por lo que las comparaciones no estarán bien hechas:

```
   Lo que haces ahora                Lo que debería hacer

B es igual que A? [i = 0; j = 0]   |  B = A? [i = 0; j = 0] 
B es igual que B? [i = 0; j = 1]   |  B = B? [i = 1; j = 1] 
B es igual que C? [i = 0; j = 2]   |  A = A? [i = 2; j = 2]
```

Lo normal es que el índice `i` también vaya incrementándose para comparar palabras.

**Solucion:**

Lo que tienes que hacer es ir comparando la cadena principal desde `i` hasta `i + tamaño de la palabra que se busca`.

```
if(cadenaprincipal[i + j] ==  cadena1[j]){
       ...
}
```

De esa manera ambas cadenas se van comparando mano a mano.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Muchísimo más claro. ¡Mil gracias!